# WebCamTexture not displayed in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to display web camera input on scene, using `WebCamTexture`. I've created a Sprite with some default texture and attached following script to it:

```
public class CameraTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play();
    }
}
```

But, when I run the scene (on PC), the camera input isn't displayed, only the default texture. 
Here is what I know:

- `webcamTexture` isn't null, the device is properly found
- camera device works properly
- other apps aren't blocking the camera

Why is the camera input not displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution myself.

The `webcamTexture` cannot be displayed on Sprite. 
I had to create a GUITexture instead, then I attached the same script and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually not entirely right, I have created a small example based on Camera Capture Kit which is an asset to render the Native Camera feed (iOS/Android) and take a snapshot / photo to a texture - which makes it possible to render to a Sprite.

Here is the example of how you can render to the sprite

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190333/add-renderable-webcamtexture-in-spriterender-unity2d/36889806#36889806
```

Essentially what you have to do is to make sure that the input of the camera is set on a secondary material texture unit in a custom shader, then you create a sprite with a empty white texture and you give the sprite renderer a referance to the texture.

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture2D texty = new Texture2D (webcamTextures.width, webcamTextures.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
texty.SetPixels (webcamTextures.GetPixels());
texty.Apply ();

Rect newRect = new Rect (0f, 0f, texty.width, texty.height);
Vector2 pivot = new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f);
imageUI.sprite = Sprite.Create (texty, newRect, pivot, 100f);
```