# Add renderable WebCamTexture in SpriteRender Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to add renderable WebCamTexture in SpriteRender Unity2D?

```
WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
webcamTexture.Play();
renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture; //not displayed
```

Comment: Just a hunch but every bit of documentation assigns the texture before calling `Play`. Could you try reversing the last two lines?

Answer (score 0):

We made a project with a plugin called Camera Capture Kit on assetstore (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 ) that takes the WebCamTexture and works with that. There are snippets of code that can be used for what you want.

You cannot change the texture directly but what can be dons is to create a material with a shader with a second texture.

```
Shader "Unlit/SpriteWebCamTexture"
{
 Properties 
 {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {} 
    _BlendTex ("Blend (RGB)", 2D) = "white"
 }
 SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Pass {
        SetTexture[_BlendTex] {
            ConstantColor[_Color]
            Combine texture * constant, constant
        }
    }
 }

 Fallback "Transparent/VertexLit"
 }
```

In your script you set the _BlendTex property to the webCamTexture like this.

```
spriteMaterial.SetTexture("_BlendTex", cameraCaptureKitController.GetWebCamTexture() );
```

This can be done in a Update method to ensure its set.

The material of the Sprite renderer is set in an Awake function like this.

```
cameraPreviewSpriteRenderer.material = webCamMat;
webCamMat.EnableKeyword( "_BlendTex" );
```

Now, in order for the sprite renderer to render anything at all you must also make sure that it has a Sprite to define its size , so what can be done is to create an empty white texture with the dimensions that you want to render in and, viola, you now have a SpriteRenderer displaying your a WebCamTexture feed.

Cheers